# Centering properlly-Jquery while appending elements

Tags: jquery

I'm appending elements to my container div on each cycle ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJCc/25/)) and centering in different positions (left,top,right,bottom); but if you look at the top position it is not centered properly! Why is that?

For centering on the top position, I'm doing:

```
         top: 0,
        right: (docWidth / 2) + $mainMenu.width()/2,
        left: (docWidth / 2) - $mainMenu.width()/2
```

And the second problem is that for left position, I dont know why I have to add 4 in the following code:

```
         left: (docWidth - $mainMenu.width()-4),
            top: (docHeight / 2) - 20,
            bottom: (docHeight / 2) + 20
```

If you delete 4 it goes out of the browser! Why do I need 4 here?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

### Issue #1

Regarding your need to subtract 4 when calculating `left` position, I believe this is caused by the fact that the text content of each button can extend beyond the boundaries of its button.

As a result, when a button moves all the way to the right side, its text content extends beyond the boundaries of the window and causes a scrollbar.

Add `overflow:hidden` to buttons so that text contents will not overflow.

```
.menuBtn {
    ...
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then you can remove the `-4`:

```
left: (docWidth - $mainMenu.width()),
```

### Issue #2

Regarding the buttons not being centered at the topmost position, I believe this is caused by two things.

First, each button has a left margin, including the first button in the row. This margin throws off the centering. Eliminate the left margin from the first button:

```
#link1  {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Also, since your animation function is run on a timer, its possible that it is called before the previous animation is complete. As a result, the calculated width of the button set may not be accurate.

I moved your function call out of the timer and into the callback of the last animation:

```
...
, 1000,function(){
    $( "#container" ).append( "<div class='menuBtn' ><span>test!</span></div>" );       
    my_animation();
})
```

Solving those two issues seemed to help:

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJCc/26/)

Comment: Wow! Such a nice explanation! Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me meticulously!